# Find the smallest integer constant $c$ such that $f(n) = \mathcal{O}(n^c )$

Tags: asymptotics

Find the smallest integer constant $c$ such that $f(n) = \mathcal{O}(n^c)$.

There are two parts to this.

In the first part, $f(n) = \dfrac{n^2}{2}$.

From what I understand, if $f(n) = \mathcal{O}(n^c)$, then $$\dfrac{f(n)}{n^c} \leq x \implies \dfrac{n^{2}}{2n^{c}} = x$$ where x is some constant.

I don't know how to proceed from here though.

In the second part, $f(n)$ is $n (\log_{2} n)^3$.

I don't know how to operate with logs. Some guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: That is an unusual definition of $O(n^c)$.  Why is the same $c$ on both sides of the equality?

Comment: Perhaps I'm reading it wrong. Perhaps the c on the two sides are different. Would it make more sense then? I'm super confused either way

Comment: Yes, that would be much better.

Comment: @Michael Burr Updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$O(g(n))$ is often written in terms of limits (or limsup), but this definition can work.

$f(n)=O(g(n))$ if there exists a $C$ so that $\frac{f(n)}{g(n)}\leq C$ for all $n$.

- In your first problem, you're trying to find $c$ and potentially $C$ so that
  $$
  \frac{\frac{1}{2}n^2}{n^c}\leq C
  $$
  for all $n$.  Therefore, you need
  $$
  n^{2-c}\leq 2C=K
  $$
  (we can define $2C$ as a new constant $K$ because both are just constants).
  Therefore, you need to know the smallest $c$ where $n^{2-c}$ is bounded.  If $c<2$, then the exponent is positive and the quantity grows as $n$ does.  if $c=2$, then the exponent is $0$ and $n^0=1$, which is bounded.  Therefore, the answer is $c=2$.
- In your second problem, $c=2$.  In
  $$
  \frac{n(\log_2 n)^3}{n^c},
  $$
  if $c\leq 1$, then the fraction is $n^{1-c}(\log_2 n)^3$, which grows because the exponent on $n$ is nonnegative and $\log_2 n$ is increasing.  On the other hand, for any $c>1$, the quantity is bounded (take the limit as $n$ approaches $\infty$).  Therefore, $c=2$ will work.

Comment: Can you explain why, for the second problem, c > 1 wouldn't work?

Comment: I read the problem wrong, I thought that $c$ had to be a real number, I missed it would be an integer.  Fixed.